# Django-Reactjs : No Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is present on the requested resource

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, django, django-cors-headers

I'm trying to load an image from an image url and try to crop that image.

Access to image at 'https://example.com/image.png' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I'm using React and Django.

app.js

```
import { useState,useCallback,useRef, useEffect} from 'react';
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactCrop from "react-image-crop";
import 'react-image-crop/dist/ReactCrop.css'

function App() {
 const [crop, setCrop] = useState({ aspect: 1.7777777777777777,
  height: 84.92083740234375,
  unit: "px",
  width: 325.97037760416663,
  x: 0,
  y: 140.07916259765625}
  );

 function onImageLoad() {
     const image = new Image();
      image.src =  "https://example.com/image.png";
      image.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
     
    const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    

    const scaleX = image.naturalWidth / image.width;
    const scaleY = image.naturalHeight / image.height;
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    const pixelRatio = window.devicePixelRatio;

    canvas.width = crop.width * pixelRatio * scaleX;
    canvas.height = crop.height * pixelRatio * scaleY;

    ctx.setTransform(pixelRatio, 0, 0, pixelRatio, 0, 0);
    ctx.imageSmoothingQuality = 'high';

    image.onload = function() {
  ctx.drawImage(
      image,
      crop.x * scaleX,
      crop.y * scaleY,
      crop.width * scaleX,
      crop.height * scaleY,
      0,
      0,
      crop.width * scaleX,
      crop.height * scaleY
    );
    }

 const base64Image = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1);
            setResult(base64Image);
            console.log(result);
  }

    useEffect(() => {
    onImageLoad();
 
   
  }, []);

return ( 
   {
                result &&
                <div>
                    <h2>Cropped Image</h2>
                    <img
                        alt="Cropped Image"
                        src={result}
                        crossorigin="anonymous"
                         style={{
                      width: Math.round(crop?.width ?? 0),
                      height: Math.round(crop?.height ?? 0)
          }}
                    />
                </div>
            }
)

}

export default App;
```

settings.py

declared everything which was required for CORS Headers still no result.

```
"""
Django settings for parkinglot project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.2.9.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/
"""
import os.path
from pathlib import Path
from corsheaders.defaults import default_headers

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-x1nb#2y!#da7w*1lij@m7*&)x&aq#8i9noxued&*n^rah$qj@5'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'backend.apps.BackendConfig',
    'frontend.apps.FrontendConfig',
    'corsheaders',
    'rest_framework',
    
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'parkinglot.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../parkinglot/frontend/','build')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'parkinglot.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        #'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        #'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'parkinglot',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = ["http://127.0.0.1:8000", 
"http://localhost:8000"]

CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = [
    "accept",
    "accept-encoding",
    "authorization",
    "content-type",
    "dnt",
    "origin",
    "user-agent",
    "x-csrftoken",
    "x-requested-with",
]
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = [
    "GET",
    "OPTIONS",
    "PATCH",
    "POST",
    "PUT",
    "DELETE"
    
]
# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'frontend', 'build', 'static')]
# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think adding the endpoint of the image to CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS will help in resolving the issue.

```
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = ["http://127.0.0.1:8000","http://localhost:8000","https://example.com/image.png"]
```

Also, make sure that if you are env then add the endpoint to the ALLOWDED HOST in the env.